# Count() returns incorrect result on IEnumerable<T> filled using LINQ

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq

To begin with, I have this inexplicable affection to LINQ and lambda expressions :)

So I wrote a quite straightforward code using LINQ, which is supposed to get files from a directory according to a certain name pattern, order them and accumulate until the total length of accumulated files exceeds a certain threshold:

```
IEnumerable<FileInfo> l_allFiles = new DirectoryInfo(l_sDirName).GetFiles().Where(l_fileInfo => ms_pattern.IsMatch(l_fileInfo.Name)).OrderBy(l_fileInfo => l_fileInfo.CreationTime);
int l_nFilesTotal = l_allFiles.Count();
if (nFilesTotal > 0)
{
    long l_nAccumulatedCmdLength = 0;
    IEnumerable<FileInfo> l_selectedFiles = l_allFiles.TakeWhile(l_fileInfo => (l_nAccumulatedCmdLength += l_fileInfo.Length) <= Settings.Default.Threshold);

    int l_nNumOfSelected = l_selectedFiles.Count();
    if (l_nNumOfSelected > 0)
    {
        l_ret = new A { Files = l_selectedFiles };
    }
}
```

Well, this code works fine when all found files together do not exceed the threshold.
As soon as not all found files are selected to `l_selectedFiles`, in most cases `l_selectedFiles.Count()` returns **0** even though `l_selectedFiles` is not empty.
In rare cases, when `l_selectedFiles.Count()` returns the correct value, the consecutive call to `Files.Count()` in the *A* class returns **0**.
To add to the mistery, the debugger always updates the value of `l_nAccumulatedLength` not after execution of the `TakeWhile()` method, but after executing the next `l_selectedFiles.Count()` statement. In cases that not all files are selected, the value of `l_nAccumulatedLength` is not always as expected...
To complete the picture, I use *Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate* on *Windows 7 Professional* and my project targets to *.NET4.0*.

Can anybody give an explanation or a hint to this behavior and/or how to fix it? Because I am quite lost and cannot even imagine how exactly I debug and resolve this issue, and the community is my last hope.

Thank you all in advance for your replies and comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're modifying a variable within a query:

```
long l_nAccumulatedCmdLength = 0;
IEnumerable<FileInfo> l_selectedFiles = l_allFiles
     .TakeWhile(l_fileInfo => (l_nAccumulatedCmdLength += l_fileInfo.Length) <=
                                   Settings.Default.Threshold);
```

Note the change to `l_nAccumulatedCmdLength` within your `TakeWhile` condition.

That's a *really bad idea*, which will end up with the sequence giving different results each time you evaluate it. Just don't do it. I strongly suspect that's the cause of the problem.

Note that this part:

> To add to the mistery, the debugger always updates the value of l_nAccumulatedLength not after execution of the TakeWhile() method, but after executing the next l_selectedFiles.Count() statement.

... is very easily explained. `TakeWhile` doesn't iterate over the sequence - it just builds a new sequence which will be lazily evaluated.

If you want to get consistent results, use `ToList`... but it would be much better not to modify a variable in the query in the first place. Use `Aggregate` to create a sequence of `Tuple<FileInfo, long>` values where the `long` value is the "size so far" if you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply.

Indeed, my assumption was that TakeWhile is some kind of immediate iteration over the sequence. If it is not, then the condition to TakeWhile does not make much sense :)

Can you elaborate a bit on your solution with Aggregate()? If I'm not mistaking, Aggregate() returns a value, not a sequence - so how exactly I get a sequence of Tuple<FileInfo, long> in an efficient manner?